# Link to full image displayed from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, image, multidimensional-array, display

Haloo, I tried much times to display big images($big) from a multidimensional array(my DB).The solution is near but I've not found it.
I'm sure that the problem are the following codes from **home.php**:

```
 <?php foreach ($product['images']['big'] as $big): ?>
     <a href="<?php echo $big ?>">
         <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am very grateful if you could help me.Thx.

**products.php:**

```
return [
    [
        'slug' => 'red-t-shirt',
        'name' => 'Red t-shirt',
        'price' => 'Euro 8',
        'size' => 'X',
        'images' => [
            'small' => [
                'photo/small_photos/1/pic1.jpg',
                'photo/small_photos/1/pic2.jpg',
            ],
            'thumg' => [
                'photo/small_photos/1/pic1.jpg',
                'photo/small_photos/1/pic2.jpg'
            ],
            'big' => [ 
            'photo/big_photos/2/pic11.jpg',
            'photo/big_photos/2/pic22.jpg',
            ],
        ],
    ],

];
```

Here is **Home.php:**

```
<div class="card-deck">
    <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>

     <?php foreach($product['images']['small'] as $image ): ?>

       <?php foreach ($product['images']['big'] as $big): ?>
     <a href="<?php echo $big ?>">
         <?php endforeach; ?>
     <img src="<?php echo $image ?>">
     </a>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php echo'<li>' .$product['name'] . '<br>' . 'Size:' . $product['size'] . '<br/>' . 'Rate:' . $product['price']
            . '</li>'
            ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the items in each of the image arrays correspond directly, you can use the key from one array to refer to the corresponding value in another.

```
<?php foreach($product['images']['small'] as $key => $image ): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $product['images']['big'][$key] ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $image ?>">
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

I think this would be more straightforward if you could modify products.php to return the data like this instead:

```
'images' => [
    ['small' => 'photo/small_photos/1/pic1.jpg',
     'thumg' => 'photo/small_photos/1/pic1.jpg',
     'big' => 'photo/big_photos/2/pic11.jpg',
    ],
    ['small' => 'photo/small_photos/1/pic2.jpg',
     'thumg' => 'photo/small_photos/1/pic2.jpg',
     'big' => 'photo/big_photos/2/pic22.jpg'
    ],
],
```

That would let you output the values more neatly:

```
<?php foreach($product['images'] as $image ): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $image['big'] ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $image['small'] ?>">
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If the items in the three different image arrays *do not* correspond directly, then you pretty much have to do this, because otherwise there's no way to tell which one goes with which.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing I'd better indent your code when nesting loops. Makes it a lot easier to read.

What you can do assuming the same number of elements under big, small, thumb...

```
<div class="card-deck">

    <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
        <li><?= $product['name'] ?><br>Size: <?= $product['size'] ?><br/>Rate: <?= $product['price'] ?></li>
        <?php foreach ($product['images']['big'] as $offset => $bigUrl): ?>
            <a href="<?= $bigUrl ?>"><img src="<?= $product['images']['small'][$offset] ?>" /></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

Those elements have keys, numeric indexes in this case. Using a single loop over the images, use that common offset value to retrieve the other values.

Comment: Thank you very much for help gentlemens.I'm still a PHP beginner but this script has made me learn and will be usefull for me in the future. SOLVED.